# vkGetSwapChainImages crashes after first call

Tags: c++, vulkan

I started learning Vulkan and everything went quite well, but somehow, the function vkGetSwapChainImages() wants to ruin my life.
Basically, this is how I create the SwapChain. desiredFormat, desiredExtent, desiredUsage, desiredExtent and desiredTransform are all set well.

```
    VkSwapchainCreateInfoKHR swapChainCreateInfo = { };
    swapChainCreateInfo.sType = VkStructureType::VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SWAPCHAIN_CREATE_INFO_KHR;
    swapChainCreateInfo.flags = 0;
    swapChainCreateInfo.pNext = nullptr;
    swapChainCreateInfo.compositeAlpha = VkCompositeAlphaFlagBitsKHR::VK_COMPOSITE_ALPHA_OPAQUE_BIT_KHR;
    swapChainCreateInfo.imageColorSpace = desiredFormat.colorSpace;
    swapChainCreateInfo.imageFormat = desiredFormat.format;
    swapChainCreateInfo.imageExtent = desiredExtent;
    swapChainCreateInfo.clipped = VK_TRUE;
    swapChainCreateInfo.imageArrayLayers = 1;
    swapChainCreateInfo.imageSharingMode = VkSharingMode::VK_SHARING_MODE_EXCLUSIVE;
    swapChainCreateInfo.surface = mRenderingSurface;
    swapChainCreateInfo.imageUsage = desiredUsage;
    swapChainCreateInfo.minImageCount = desiredImageCount;
    swapChainCreateInfo.presentMode = desiredMode;
    swapChainCreateInfo.oldSwapchain = oldSwapChain;
    swapChainCreateInfo.pQueueFamilyIndices = nullptr;
    swapChainCreateInfo.queueFamilyIndexCount = 0;
    swapChainCreateInfo.preTransform = desiredTransform;

    if ( vkCreateSwapchainKHR( mLogicalDevice, &swapChainCreateInfo, nullptr, &mSwapChain ) != VK_SUCCESS )
        return false;
```

If I call vkGetSwapChainImages nothing bad happens. But if I want to call vkGetSwapChainImages a second time, it doesn't work and I get an exception like this

```
Exception thrown at 0x0433A209 (VkLayer_core_validation.dll) in Project1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x000000A8.
```

And I don't understand why this happens. I tried saving the results from first call and using them, but I still get an error, so I that there's something I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: It crashes in the validation layers. There should be a validation error message preceding the crash. If there is not it means either some pointer is invalid (unbacked by memory) or the layers are buggy/incomplete.

Comment: Try disabling validation layers and check if this helps. If it is, it may be a bug in validation layers.

Comment: PS: Simply doing `vkGetSwapChainImages` twice works for me.

Comment: Calling this function twice is allowed or even quite common, as the first call gives us the number of available images (when we pass null for the last parameter), and second call gives us the actual handles (with a valid pointer passed in the last parameter). But we can call this function any number of times we want.

Comment: @krOoze, I disabled validation layers, it works now. But I still don't get the result I want (first triangle), I'll keep debugging ... I thought that maybe if I fix this, i'll be able to fix everything and get the triangle.

Comment: @Kavarna If it works without validation layers, I think You should submit a bug so they get fixed.